# Detect battery change

Tags: windows-7, battery

We have all the same laptops in the area were we work. Last week, I noticed that my (10 month old) battery suddenly drained within 5 minutes (from 1hour+ one month ago). I suspect a battery change from an old laptop to my and vice-versa may be happened.

Is there a way to detect this in Microsoft Windows 7?

Comment: Sign your name on your battery or record its serial number.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you recorded this information before hand. I doubt there will be any log of this happening, but the battery will have a serial number and some machines can detect this through software.

Perhaps check if it looks any physically different (any scuffs overlapping the plastics of your case and your battery?). Otherwise, sorry.